# GAE JPA query with Ancestor

Tags: google-app-engine, jpa, ancestor

I'm trying to figure out what's the proper way to have a jpa query with ancestor on GAE.

There are two class: book and publisher;
Book has one publisher but publisher has multiple books.

here is the one without ancesor:

```
Query query = mgr.createQuery("select from Book as Book"); 
execute = (List<Book>) query.getResultList();
```

How can I do the correct query with publisher as the ancestor in the query? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You first have to get the Publisher's Key. You can use a key-based query or if you have the Publisher's ID you can just do:

```
Key key = KeyFactory.createKey(Publisher.class.getSimpleName(), publisherId);
```

Once you have the Key, you can do:

```
query.setAncestor(key);
```

EDIT: I didn't realise this is the way to do it in JDO. Not sure in JPA but I think it's similar...